# Jasper report Server connection fail when connect to mysql

Tags: java, mysql, olap, jasperserver, olap-cube

when i am creating the connection in jasper report server with mysql and then testing the connection it shows me CONNECTION FAILED. Plz help me 
also tell me how i can create olap connection between jasper report server and java

Comment: Can you connect a query tool to the DB?  Can you route (maybe ping?) the DB server?  Do you have the right port etc?

Answer (score 0):

Late,but might be useful to others.

For the connection to fail their may be 2-3 possiblities.
1) Try to check the driver for connection.For Mysql it is **mysql-connector-java-5.1.12-bin.jar**.

2) Try to write a simple Java program for DB connection and see if it works.If this works then it should also be possible through Jasper as there are no environment issues.

3) *jdbc:mysql://localhost/DBname* Check the connection string in jasper/ireports in this format.

Finally also check for Uname/Passwd credentials to be right.

hope it helps.

All the best cheers.